# Why doesn't a sub-function inherit scope in Python?

Tags: python, scope

I don't understand why the following doesn't work:

```
def foo( x ):
    n = 1
    summe = 0
    def bar():
        n -= 1
    for i in range(0,10):
        y = x+i+n
        x += i
        summe += y
        print "{0} = {1} + {2} + {3}".format(y,x,i,n)
        bar()
    print "summe =", summe
    return summe
```

Why is it that `bar()` doesn't inherit the scope of `foo()`?  Is this a C'ism that I need to forget?  Is there a way I can make that work?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Version 2.6.6.  Is this addressed in a newer version?

Comment: It cannot be a C-ism - in C a function cannot have "inner functions".

Comment: BTW, I hope it is just an example. It is completely pointless to use this function instead of just doing `n -= 1` where it is needed...

Comment: @glglgl That's not true.  This code is valid (make sure to add in `#include <stdio.h>` at the top): `int main() { char test_me[] = "this is a test\n"; void my_print(){ printf(test_me);} my_print(); return 0; }`  GCC gives a warning about it, but it does work.

Comment: @glglgl And also, that wasn't really the point here.  This is a rather contrived example to ask about scope.

Comment: @supercheetah [Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) it is described as a GCC extension. In Standard C it is *not* valid.

Comment: @glglgl Yup, I'll have to admit that you're correct.  My apologies.  I guess I'd been working with just GCC for too long--not that I've had need for nested functions in C, but I knew they were possible with GCC.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) provides an explanation and a solution for this problem. The issue is Python treats any assignment to a name as a *local* variable declaration.

```
>>> n = 1
>>> def bar():
>>>     n = n + 1
>>> 
>>> bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    bar()
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 2, in bar
    n = n + 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment
```

There is a few workarounds for this problem if you use a Python version without the **nonlocal** keyword. One ugly trick is to wrap your variable in a list:

```
>>> n=[1]
>>> def bar():
>>>     n[0] = n[0] + 1
>>> 
>>> bar()
>>> n
[2]
```

Although this trick works, it is usually better to rewrite the code to remove the need for non-local assignments.

Comment: That is ugly, but at least it works.  There are some things in which having access to the nonlocal variable would be useful, such as in a `for` loop with a bunch of `elif`s for some kind of reset function.  I've used some lambdas to work around the problem, but they're limited in their functionality.

Comment: Because you can use subscript assignment, which does not declare a new variable in the local context.

Answer (score 2):

I actually found this question while searching for a solution to a slightly different problem. Local variables aren't inherited by sub's inherited but there's nothing stopping you from passing the variable to the inner function and then assigning the results on return.

This is in addition to the `nonlocal` statement in [PEP 3104](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/).  It's slightly less ugly and makes memorizing yet another python keyword less crucial.

```
def foo( x ):
    n = 1
    summe = 0
    def bar(n):
        n -= 1
        return n
    for i in range(0,10):
        n = bar(n)
        y = x+i+n
        x += i
        summe += y
        print "{0} = {1} + {2} + {3}".format(y,x,i,n)
    print "summe =", summe
    return summe
```

Comment: There's no point in passing `summe` to `bar()`. Besides, your `bar()` returns `None`, and it is not about modifying `summe`, but `n`.

Comment: I was paraphrasing.  The point was to find a hack to simulate scope inheritance.